# How to get displayed unicode in python shell

Tags: python

I am trying `python-sympy` on Emacs using the the python shell. Problem arise when I try to display unicode characters. This is what I get:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x = symbols('x')
>>> init_printing(use_unicode=True)
>>> solve(x**2 -2, x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sympy-0.7.7.dev-py2.7.egg/sympy/interactive/printing.py", line 30, in _displayhook
      print(stringify_func(arg))
  UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u221a' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there a way of displaying unicode (I did not tried `ein-package`)?

Comment: Are you sure this is Emacs-specific and cannot be reproduced outside Emacs?

Comment: Yes. Tried on Terminal it correctly displays unicode `[-√2, √2]`

Comment: Could this be related to the locale of the shell running in Emacs? What if you try: `import locale; locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'en_US.UTF-8')` before you print out the Unicode characters?

Comment: I got the same error. `from sympy import *;import locale;locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'en_US.UTF-8') ;init_printing(use_unicode=True);solve(x**2 -2,x)`

Comment: Interesting.  I can't get this to work in emacs either, or iTerm2, but it DOES work in OSX Terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135522/iterm2-unicode-and-sympy) StackExchange answer.  Basically, you need to be sure that the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable is set to `utf-8`

To try this out in your running emacs you can do M-x setenv and answer the prompts accordingly.

So, this isn't actually an emacs specific problem at all.  I saw the same problem and the same solution worked in iTerm2.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get this working in Emacs.app in addition to setting PYTHIONIOENCODING, I also had to set the LANG variable, I now have the following lines in my `.emacs`:

```
 (setenv "PYTHONIOENCODING" "utf-8")
 (setenv "LANG" "en_US.UTF-8")
```